# Stored procedure from Oracle not returning Control to .NET process

Tags: c#, oracle, session-timeout, oracle-manageddataaccess

I've 1 .NET process developed in C# that uses Oracle.DataAccess Library to connect to our Oracle Database. My process does some massive updates, and after them must call a stored procedure in Oracle to do some stuff. This procedure tooks 1,5 hours to finalize (I can see that it has finished because i've a control table associated to this procedure), but C# code remains in same line while debugging... Can be some kind of timeout? I left proccess running yesterday and when i arrive today process is still running (14 hours), and the stored procedure finished in 1,5 hours...).

Is There a way to control this?

Method that calls the procedure:

```
public bool PostCurrentJob()
    {
        Logger.Log.Debug(Logger.Direction.INPUT);

        string jobName = ActiveJob;
        bool result = true;
        if (jobName == null)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        else
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = dbManager.GetOracleCommand("genesis_admin_pkg.post");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            try
            {
                OracleParameter pJobName = new OracleParameter("p_Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
                pJobName.Value = jobName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pJobName);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.Log.Error(e);
                throw e;
            }
        }
        Logger.Log.Debug(Logger.Direction.OUTPUT);
        return result;
    }
```

Code executions stops in cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Thanks!